# How to reuse custom methods in a simpletest class?

Tags: testing

I have created several test methods that I find useful in a lot of other situations.

All I need is to define an include file of higher visibility which contains an utility class which is autoloaded in every .test file throughout my Drupal modules.

Is this possible in the Simpletest framework?